# How to enhance a json object?

Tags: javascript, json, angular, typescript

I am recieving a json object from an api as following:

```
[
    {"id":998,
        "client":{"id":"AF01072","name":"Vivek","lastName":"Joshi","phone":123},
        "membership":{"type":"Semi-Annually","price":18000},
        "start_date":"2019-11-19","end_date":"2020-05-16","payment":12000,"balance":0
    },

    {"id":1004,
        "client":{"id":"AF01072","name":"Vivek","lastName":"Joshi","phone":123},
        "membership":{"type":"Annually","price":30000},
        "start_date":"2020-08-27","end_date":"2021-08-27","payment":30000,"balance":5000,
    }
]
```

in angular when I loop to print the data 'client' information prints two times, because it is repeated two times.

```
<div *ngFor="let c of clientinfo">
  {{c.client.name}}
  {{c.membership.type}}
  {{c.membership.price}}
  {{c.start_date}}
  {{c.end_date}}
        .
        .
        .
</div>
```

How can I enhance this data so I get only client information once but the rest stay as they are?

thanks in advance

Comment: Filter the array to include unique values only, based on some id like `client#id`

Comment: can you please show me how?

Comment: you can do this by using map function

Comment: are you looking to just filter the repetitive client information in UI, or you want to modify the structure mentioned in your question by removing the repetitive info from the object itself?

Comment: @AhmadShoaibRafa did the answer resolved your issue? ;)

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you need to group some data by some value you can use an object because object properties are guaranteed to never be duplicated. You have to be careful however because properties can be overwritten.

First, let's settle on a structure that works. The following is one such structure that can work:

```
{
    [client.id] : {
        client: client,
        info : [
            { membership, start_date },
            { membership, start_date },
            ..
        ]
    },
    [client.id] : {
        client: client,
        info : [
            { membership, start_date },
            { membership, start_date },
            ..
        ]
    },
    ..
}
```

There are other ways to arrange the data but the key is to exploit objects to implement a map/hash/associative array of key/value pairs. With this we can group the data from your array:

```
let group = {};

jsonData.forEach(x => {
    // check if group already contain this client:
    if (!group[x.client.id]) {
        // auto-create array if does not exist
        group[x.client.id] = {
            client: x.client,
            info: []
        };
    }

    group[x.client.id].info.push({
        membership: x.membership,
        start_date: x.start_date
    });
});
```

Now you have an object grouped by client id where each property is an object that has an `info` array that contains membership information.

If you need to loop over this data structure you can convert it back to an array by doing:

```
let groupArray = Object.values(group);
```

This will give you the following data structure:

```
[
    {
        client: client,
        info : [
            { membership, start_date },
            { membership, start_date },
            ..
        ]
    },
    {
        client: client,
        info : [
            { membership, start_date },
            { membership, start_date },
            ..
        ]
    },
    ..
]
```

An array of client objects with an `info` property containing an array of membership data. For your sample data it would be something like:

```
[
    {
        "client":{"id":"AF01072","name":"Vivek","lastName":"Joshi","phone":123},
        "info": [
            {
                "membership":{"type":"Semi-Annually","price":18000},
                "start_date":"2019-11-19",
                "end_date":"2020-05-16",
                "payment":12000,"balance":0
            },
            {
                "membership":{"type":"Annually","price":30000},
                "start_date":"2020-08-27",
                "end_date":"2021-08-27",
                "payment":30000,"balance":5000,
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create array of `memberships` for each client like below. And in the template file, you need to use two `*ngFor` loops. One to loop client details and another one to loop the respective client's membership details.

Working [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ej4ahz?file=src/app/app.component.html)

```js
const result = [{
    "id": 998,
    "client": {
      "id": "AF01072",
      "name": "Vivek",
      "lastName": "Joshi",
      "phone": 123
    },
    "membership": {
      "type": "Semi-Annually",
      "price": 18000
    },
    "start_date": "2019-11-19",
    "end_date": "2020-05-16",
    "payment": 12000,
    "balance": 0
  },

  {
    "id": 1004,
    "client": {
      "id": "AF01072",
      "name": "Vivek",
      "lastName": "Joshi",
      "phone": 123
    },
    "membership": {
      "type": "Annually",
      "price": 30000
    },
    "start_date": "2020-08-27",
    "end_date": "2021-08-27",
    "payment": 30000,
    "balance": 5000,
  },

  {
    "id": 1005,
    "client": {
      "id": "AF01073",
      "name": "Some Other",
      "lastName": "Joshi",
      "phone": 123
    },
    "membership": {
      "type": "Annually",
      "price": 30000
    },
    "start_date": "2020-08-27",
    "end_date": "2021-08-27",
    "payment": 30000,
    "balance": 5000,
  }
].reduce((acc, item, i) => {
  if (i == 0) {
    acc.push(constructCorrectObject(item));
    return acc;
  }
  let foundItem = acc.find(it => it.id === item.client.id);
  if (foundItem) {
    addMemeberShipDetails(foundItem, item);
    return acc;
  } else {
    acc.push(constructCorrectObject(item));
    return acc;
  }
}, []);

function constructCorrectObject(item) {
  return {
    "id": item.client.id,
    "name": item.client.name,
    "lastName": item.client.lastName,
    "phone": item.client.phone,
    "membership": [{
      "id": item.id,
      "type": item.membership.type,
      "price": item.membership.price,
      "start_date": item.start_date,
      "end_date": item.end_date,
      "payment": item.payment,
      "balance": item.balance,
    }]
  }
}

function addMemeberShipDetails(acc, item) {
  acc.membership.push({
    "id": item.id,
    "type": item.membership.type,
    "price": item.membership.price,
    "start_date": item.start_date,
    "end_date": item.end_date,
    "payment": item.payment,
    "balance": item.balance,
  });
}

console.log(result);
```